# Is there difference between echo "example" and "example" out of PHP tags?

Tags: php, tags, echo

Is there a difference between this

```
<?php
    myCode();
    echo "Example";
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    myCode();
?>
Example
```

this?

What is the best choice in terms of performance?

I've done a Benchmark printing 20000000 times "Example". I've executed the script from CLI, not through HTTP request (Centos 7 64bit).

Using "echo": 153.06723901367sec

Using HTML: 155.80555395508sec

Comment: What do you mean by **views**?

Comment: There is no practical difference. Go with whatever is more readable.

Comment: @shashi I'm not understanding: both works. I want to know if there are differences (performance, system calls, ecc). Why all of you are downvoting?

Comment: @shashi: "remove php script from last one"??

Comment: @Swellar I mean views. Do you know MVC?

Comment: `myCode();` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @JJJ In the first case there is an echo: isn't it a system call?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay are you seriosuly? it is an example.

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834520/is-there-harm-in-outputting-html-vs-using-echo

Comment: @kerbholz, just kidding but it will work as I can see from the script his only interest is to print example

Comment: At this level it really doesn't make any significant difference. It is just about readability.

Comment: What do you mean by a "system call"? (It usually means calling native OS methods but that doesn't make sense in this context.) Whatever the difference is in any regard, it's so small that I doubt it'd be even possible to measure it.

Comment: @jjj Sorry: I mean a simple function call, not system call. echo is a function so I think that calling it, there is one more step compared to the first example.

Comment: @JustCarty that question does not speak about performance

Comment: Half of the duplicate's answers talk about performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all pragmatic purposes, no, there is no relevant difference. Your script output will be "Example" in both cases. And in both cases, myCode() was executed before.

In fact, the OPCodes in both cases will be the same, because PHP will echo everything outside of `<?php` tags. It's basically just an implicit echo.

Technically, the way to the resulting OPCodes will be different, but this has no relevant impact on performance. Mostly anything outside `<?php` tags is treated as `T_INLINE_HTML` by the parser. This is then [converted to an echo in the abstract syntax tree](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L440):

```
|   T_INLINE_HTML { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_ECHO, $1); }
```

with [ZEND_AST_ECHO](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_ast.c#L1366-L1367) being

```
case ZEND_AST_ECHO:
APPEND_NODE_1("echo");
```

However, your aim should be to separate logic from your views and templates as good as possible as it can easily lead to spaghetti code if you don't. As a rule of thumb, a function should not echo, but return strings. Most frameworks only echo once: at the end of a request when rendering the response.

Since you mentioned "Views" and MVC: a View in MVC is not necessarily a template, but a specific representation of a particular piece of data from the Model. It can be code that ultimately renders a template though. If that's what you want, you probably want to check out a template engine, like Twig (although PHP is a template engine on it's own).

Comment: Yes. I use usually Smarty in PHP and Handlebar in JS. It was only a question about performances, I never use views inside the logic like spaghetti code  :)

Comment: @TheDeveloper Performance wise there is no relevant difference. Also, whenever asking about performance, do yourself a favor and benchmark in the context of your application to get meaningful numbers.

Comment: OK, so I will do a benchmark.

Comment: I've read just now the edit. Wow! Interesting, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -2):

Yes. The 1st is PHP, the 2nd is HTML.

In the first case you could do:

```
<?php
$var = 1;
echo "Example " . $var;
?>
```

The second case `$var` is undefined in the HTML so would be ignored.

```
<?php
$var = 1;
?>
Example $var
```

If you wanted to use that variable in the HTML you would need to go back into PHP i.e.

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

This is a preference thing in my experience, there are some pages that are mostly HTML that can be written that way. However, if I am writing PHP I prefer to stick with PHP and not bounce between the 2 languages. I don't know of anything that you can do in HTML that you can't produce from PHP. It makes for nasty looking code that is hard to debug.
Also there are issues with HTML headers (see [PHP `header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) Function).

Comment: The OPCodes in both cases will be exactly the same.